# ingress multiple path mismatch

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have two service
serviceOld
serviceNew

I want to achieve the following effect

```
http://host/any         => http://serviceOld/any
http://host/any/aaa     => http://serviceOld/any/aaa
http://host/feature     => http://serviceNew/feature
http://host/feature/bbb => http://serviceNew/feature/bbb
```

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-by-header: new
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: v2
  namespace: api
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: serviceOld
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /feature/*
        backend:
          serviceName: serviceNew
          servicePort: 8080
```

I tried multiple methods and failed to achieve the goal. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need about rewrite `annotation` and `path` can be found in [Ingress Rewrite Docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target).

As per example on the site:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

It will redirect:

```
rewrite.bar.com/something rewrites to rewrite.bar.com/
rewrite.bar.com/something/ rewrites to rewrite.bar.com/
rewrite.bar.com/something/new rewrites to rewrite.bar.com/new
```

In your case it should looks like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: v2
  namespace: api
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xxx.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /any(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: serviceOld
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /feature(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: serviceNew
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, I need help very much now.

In your example, if I visit http://host/any/foo, it will rewrite to http://oldHost/foo, is my understanding correct? Actually what I want is to request http://host/feature/foo => http://newHost/feature/foo, any path other than feature, or request to oldHost. like this http://host/any/foo => http://oldHost/any/foo

Answer (score 0):

I found that my version is relatively old. Under the old version, if the ports are different, it will not work properly. Change to the same port or upgrade the ingress version